# how to run node js file from php using system command in mac

Tags: javascript, php, node.js, macos

i am running a node js file using system command in php. my php code is

```js
system('cd path && node sample');
```

when i run this code in windows it is working fine . but when transported into mac it is not executing . please tell me how can i do in mac. how to run node js file from  php  using system comand in mac